# Angular error handling and logging - Call GlobalErrorHandler's handleError

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs, httpclient

I'm following an Angular error handling/logging tutorial here: https://www.code-sample.com/2017/09/angular-4-error-handling-and-logging.html

My question is - how can I call the `handleError` method (residing in the `global-error-handler.service.ts` file, seen in step 3 below) from one of my services?

In my `ErrorLogService`, I'm also instantiating a `POST` request (with data coming from a component) and using `catchError` to try and call `handleError` from `global-error-handler.service.ts`, but I'm getting *`[ts] Property 'handleError' does not exist on type 'typeof GlobalErrorHandler'.`*:

**ErrorLogService**:

```
  postData(body):Observable<any>{

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    }
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl2, body, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(GlobalErrorHandler.handleError)
    )
  }
```

**Step 1 - Create an AppConstants class (AppConstants.ts) for global error messages:**

```
export class AppConstants {
public static get baseURL(): string { return 'http://localhost:4200/api'; }
public static get httpError(): string { return 'There was an HTTP error.'; }
public static get typeError(): string { return 'There was a Type error.'; }
public static get generalError(): string { return 'There was a general error.'; }
public static get somethingHappened(): string { return 'Nobody threw an Error but something happened!'; }
}
```

**Step 2 – Create an error log service (ErrorLogService) for error logging:**

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import{ AppConstants} from '../app/constants'
// my import of globalErrorHandler, so I can (hopefully) use its handleError method
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from '../global-error-handler/global-error-handler';

//#region Handle Errors Service
@Injectable()
export class ErrorLogService {

  constructor() {  }

  //Log error method
  logError(error: any) {
    //Returns a date converted to a string using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC).
    const date = new Date().toUTCString();

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      //The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(date, AppConstants.httpError, error.message, 'Status code:',
                                                  (<HttpErrorResponse>error).status);
    }
    else if (error instanceof TypeError) {
      console.error(date, AppConstants.typeError, error.message, error.stack);
    }
    else if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error(date, AppConstants.generalError, error.message, error.stack);
    }
    else if(error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      //A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error(date, AppConstants.generalError, error.message);
    }
    else {
      console.error(date, AppConstants.somethingHappened, error.message, error.stack);
    }
  }
}
//#endregion
```

**Step 3 - Create a global error handler service (GlobalErrorHandler.service.ts) for using the error log service to log errors**

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import {ErrorLogService} from './error-log.service';

// Global error handler for logging errors
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private errorLogService: ErrorLogService) {
       //Angular provides a hook for centralized exception handling.
       //constructor ErrorHandler(): ErrorHandler
        super();
    }

    handleError(error) : void {
        this.errorLogService.logError(error);
    }
}
```

**Step 4 – In app.module.ts, import services, global handler and error handler:**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import {ErrorLogService} from './error-logg.service';
import {GlobalErrorHandler} from './global-error.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}])
  ],
  providers: [ ErrorLogService, // register global error log service
              GlobalErrorHandler,// register global error handler
              EmployeeService, // register Employee service
              ValidationService, //register Validation Service
              AuthenticationService, //register Authentication Service
              UserService],//register User Service
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!
I ended up using another tutorial where they instantiate the GlobalErrorHandlerService differently within `App.Module.ts`. Following this worked (a beautiful error handling tutorial): https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-custom-error-handler

In it, within `app.module.ts` they did the following (note the `providers` array):

```
@NgModule({
  ------
  providers: [
    GlobalErrorHandlerService,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandlerService },
    -----    
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, in my case I should never have been trying to call `handleError`. `GlobalErrorHandlerService` overrides the default `ErrorHandler`. Thus, the new `handleError` method created in my 'GlobalErrorHandlerService' will have errors thrown to it automatically or by using the 'throw' keyword (on observables that you're `.subscribe`d to).

Please take a good look at the above tutorial if you're having trouble with Angular Global Error Handling.

Comment: The first `GlobalErrorHandlerService` in the providers array is redundant